# equil button is only returning 0

Tags: jquery, calculator, equals

I am building a calculator for my class I have gotten this far however whenever i push equals it returns 0 instead of the answer i do not understand where or what to change...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var expression = "";
    function appendChar(char) {
    expression += char;
    var eval;
    try {
     result = eval(equals);


    $("#calculation").text(expression + " = " + result);
    } catch (e) {

    $("#calculation").text(expression);



    }
}



    $(".digit, .operator").click(function()    {
        appendChar($(this).text());
    });

    $(".clear").click(function()    {
        expression = "";
        $("#calculation").text("0");
    });

    $(".equals").click(function()    {

         expression = "";
        $("#calculation").text("0");

    });

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are calling:

```
$("#calculation").text("0");
```

You are making an error because '.text("0")' sets your result to "0".
Instead you will have to put the result in there.

```
$("#calculation").text(result);
```